# How to end the borrowing of an object without introducing a new scope?

Tags: rust, move-semantics, borrow-checker

I want to access an object as read-only after it has been passed to another object which changes its state. I know there is a problem with accessing an object when its still under control by being borrowed.

```
extern crate renderay_rs;

use renderay_rs::*;

fn draw_canvas(canvas: &Canvas) {
    let max_height = canvas.height;
    let max_width = canvas.width;

    for iterator_y in 0..max_height {
        for iterator_x in 0..max_width {
            print!("{}", canvas.array[iterator_y * iterator_x]);
        }
        print!("\n");
    }
}


fn main() {
    let point = Point { x: 5, y: 5 };
    let mut canvas = Canvas {
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        array: vec!['o'; 10*10],
    };

    let mut renderer = CanvasRenderer::new(&mut canvas);
    renderer.render_point('A', point);

    draw_canvas(canvas);
}
```

I feel I should end the borrowing after the `renderer.render_point(..., ...)` method. Is there a way to do so? The object has no need to be borrowed by it or the `CanvasRenderer` after its state has been changed.

I've used block scope before, but I don't feel happy with this approach. I hope you can give me a hint for a better alternative!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can introduce a block to reduce the scope of `renderer`:

```
fn main() {
    let point = Point { x: 5, y: 5 };
    let mut canvas = Canvas {
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        array: vec!['o'; 10*10],
    };

    {
        let mut renderer = CanvasRenderer::new(&mut canvas);
        renderer.render_point('A', point);
    }

    draw_canvas(canvas);
}
```

Another way if you don't like blocks is to use functions. Rust will be able to figure out where the borrow ends from the lifetimes (here the function does not return anything, so the borrow ends after the function call):

```
fn render_things(canvas: &mut Canvas) {
    let mut renderer = CanvasRenderer::new(canvas);
    renderer.render_point('A', point);
}

fn main() {
    let point = Point { x: 5, y: 5 };
    let mut canvas = Canvas {
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        array: vec!['o'; 10*10],
    };

    render_things(&mut canvas);
    draw_canvas(canvas);
}
```

Comment: thanks for that but as I said I used block scope before but am not happy with this approach - is there really no other way to do it?

Comment: I've added a way with functions. What do you don't like with blocks?

Comment: I think the answer is fine: blocks are mimicking the runtime of the code, after all. Although pedantically, using functions is just another way of introducing a new scope / block ^_^.

Comment: Yes, but as he does not say what he does not like with blocks, I'm trying to hide them :-°